# Style Transfer : Save&Restore checkpoint/model in tensorflow 1.15.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, checkpoint, style-transfer

i am a bit frustrated about saving and restoring models in tensorflow 1.15.0. I want to achieve it in a jupyter notebook / google colab notebook environment. The application is style-transfer of images.

I simply want to save the model and restore it in order to apply the style transfer for a larger number of images.

The tensorflow documentation is a bit confusing, (i did not find examples for this), so i never really know what the right syntax looks like.

I am at a point now where i want to achieve 1 thing:

1. Restore the model
   correctly.

I will write the relevant lines now:

```
model = get_model()  
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=2.5,beta1=0.99, epsilon=1e-1)
saver = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model, optimizer=opt)
saver.save('/content/sample_data/test/_____NEU____')
```

When i want to restore the model, i use the command:

```
saver.restore('/content/sample_data/test/_____NEU____')
```

How can i fix this issue, and load my checkpoint files correctly? Thank you

---

The google colab project is here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12hTitoQ2-tH8pYEsfMDR5jtsg8a96PgC

---

Comment: MIRC CHAT:      https://pastebin.com/nb6mPcFa

Answer (score 0):

I also tried saving the model via the keras - syntax.

```
model.load_weights('/content/sample_data/saved_model/my_model6.h5')
```

and

```
model.save_weights('/content/sample_data/saved_model/my_model6.h5', save_format='h5')
```

There was no error message, but the model did not load in the previously trained weights. I asked someone in a mirc-channel yesterday and he said it could be a bug in tf.keras for tensorflow 1.15.0 , but i tried it with tensorflow 1.14.0 and 1.13.1 yesterday without success.

Answer (score 0):

**This technique is one where the model doesn't change, but you update the input image to produce the desired output.**
 .. so there was nothing wrong with the saving, but the model just did not change.